# How do I capture the yield value of a Redux-Saga `call` function?

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I have a very simple function that returns an object:

```
export const fetchThing = (thingId) => ({
  description: "hi",
  thing: thingId
})
```

I'll later expand this function to perform an async action but I'm trying to keep things simple to start with.

Using Redux-Saga I'm attempting to do the following:

```
export function* requestThingSaga({payload}) {
  const thing = yield call(fetchThing, payload.thingId)
  console.log(thing);
}
```

But when I test the saga, I find that `fetchThing` is not called:

```
gen = requestThingSaga({payload: {thingId: 1 });
gen.next() // logs 'undefined'
```

I can't understand what's going on. The docs for `call` say that a function with a normal return value can be used. I can't see why this wouldn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of `redux-saga` is about making effects **"declarative"**. So you need an interpreter that will handle those effects. ReduxSaga middleware acts as such an interpreter that does actuall calls, awaiting promises etc. Otherwise it is just a declaration that (in this case) you want to call external function. So your test is kinda "testing effect interpreter" that only asserts something about which effect your saga returns w/o actually doing something "real".

```
gen = requestThingSaga({payload: {thingId: 1 });

// test by inspecting .value w/o actuall call
gen.next().value.should.be.deep.equal(call(fetchThing, 1))

// "interprete" call effect by passing a value back
gen.next({description: 'hi', thing: 1})
```

BTW `gen` should be better named `iter` :) because it is Iterator not Generator.